# Longest cycle on a cube

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization

What is the length of the longest straight path on the surface of a unit cube, such that it starts and ends at the same point?

The path can cross itself and must be straight on every edge and face that it passes.

Comment: I would like a definition of "straight" for this question. When taking literally, the only answer appears to be 0. I expect it's something like "must be a straight line on each face". Also, can the path cross itself?

Comment: Added more information

Comment: By "straight on every edge" do you mean that if the cube were unfolded so the two adjoining faces are coplanar, then the line would be straight?

Comment: Yes @WeatherVane, that's what I mean

Comment: Surely there are such paths of arbitrarily high length?

Comment: Do you want the path to avoid vertices?

Comment: The path can go through vertices. But would be interesting to see what happens when it doesn't

Comment: If you allow intersections, then you can wind around 4 faces arbitrarily many times like a spool of sewing thread before it hits one of the two other faces and cuts across to the first winding.

Comment: To visualize @Jaap Scherphuis idea, try to select certain angles, which fulfills the condition to return into origin point in finite steps, here: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThePathOfARayOnACube/

Comment: ah yes I can see now. Didn't think of that. What happens if we disallow intersections?

Comment: If a path of no thickness starts from a corner and sets out almost parallel to one edge at an angle approaching zero, then it would wrap around 4 faces of the cube with a path length approaching infinity before it has wound across to the other parallel side.

Comment: But should return to the start point.

Comment: @z100 not without crossing. I guess the maximum path length to meet without crossing is also the minimum path length: 4.

Comment: @WeatherVane  Trivial solution, two edges and two diagonals is $2+2\sqrt 2$

Comment: @z100 oh ok, yes.

Comment: In the original problem, you can just draw a straight line in any direction, extend it arbitrarily far (just avoiding to touch edges, even though I am not sure this is a problem) and trim it to the first and last intersection point.

Comment: @z100 that was my intended solution

Comment: The 'straight path' seems to still lack a definition. Does it mean that the path lines are coplanar? IOW the cube section with the longest perimeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the maximum length is

> Infinite.

Because

> You can start from the center of an edge, cross an adjacent edge, then go 4N+1 times over the opposite edge and arrange to end on the middle of the edge adjacent to the last edge you crossed.
>  This resuls in winding the line N 1/2 times around 4 faces of the cube, starting and ending in the middle of opposite edges.  Continuing straight you wind again N times around the cube over a different set of 4 edges and end up where you started.
>  This forms a perfectly straight loop.
>  Since N is arbitrary you can make it as long as you want.

PS: I did not read the comment before posing.  Other got the same idea.

Now with the restriction that the line should not intersect:

> Apply the method with N=0.  The total length is $2 \sqrt{5} = 4.4721$
>
>  [image]
>
>  If vertices are allowed, I would draw a zig-zag over 4 diagonals around the cube for a length of $4 \sqrt{2} = 5.6568$
>
>  It can be unfolded to yield a straight line:
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The last diagram for four supposed diagonals is a bit off. The line isn't really straight. You can't go four diagonals, but you can go two diagonals and two edges, as [commented](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124851/longest-cycle-on-a-cube#comment346779_124851) by @z100

Comment: As you said, it's a "zig-zag". That diagram can only be made by cutting a face diagonally.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand the objection.  These are true diagonals that go from vertex to vertex.  They are obviously perfectly aligned.  Do you complain about the image quality?
And I don't see why cutting a face diagonally to unfold should be a problem.

Comment: @FlorianF I think it's about the definition of "straightness", which is pretty clear when passing the edge, but no so clear when passing the vertex, depended on the way of flattening the cube net.

Comment: I would completely disallow going along an edge or through a vertex as it leads to too much ambiguity about straight lines. For example you could argue that two edges meeting at a vertex are in a straight line because you can unfold the cube so that they are. That leads to the possible answer of a length 8 loop, a Hamilton path visiting all vertices. If you disallow vertices you could still go infinitessimally close to them and have the same effect, but it would reject the  diagonals solution here because the loop would have to slalom between the four vertices and that is not straight.

Comment: I would allow going through an edge, but not two edges in a row.

Comment: Well, as I said "if vertices are allowed".  If you don't accept vertices, then the solution is invalid.  If you do, the behaviour at corners is ambiguous, but I believe my solution is compatible with the straightness defined via the unfolding the the cube.  z100's solution uses another idea of straightness which would make more sense mathematically.  This being said, bravo to Jaap for his ingenious 8-unit solution using (or abusing) corners.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis to get the 4 'full' diagonals shown the line would need to pass through the centre of a face, not quite parallel to the diagonal. But if the line is parallel to the diagonal and slightly offset, it only traverses 3 'full' diagonals.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as you have answered the original question that allows line intersections.